# How to set indentation type used in vim?

Tags: vim, indentation

I'm coding in `sage` (a python flavour), and I want to enable the python indentation for the filetype sage. How do I do this, without changing the filetype to python?
The reason I don't want python as filetype is that it has some unwanted side-effects, like syntastic complaining about lots of things, which are wrong in python, but correct in sage.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://wiki.sagemath.org/Tips ... although upon closer inspection, it looks like it is just using python as the filetype.

Comment: Yup, it indeed uses python filetype. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the best way but you can create indent and syntax files for sage that just source the python indent and syntax files.

In your vimrc add

```
augroup filetypedetect
  au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.sage,*.spyx,*.pyx setfiletype sage
augroup END
```

Create the file `~/.vim/syntax/sage.vim` with the following

```
runtime! syntax/python.vim
```

Create the file `~/.vim/indent/sage.vim` with the following

```
runtime! indent/python.vim
```

Comment: Instead of `source $VIMRUNTIME/` you can use `runtime!`; then it will also pick up user-specific overrides.

Comment: It's better than nothing :) The syntax file doesn't have to be sourced however. Vim has the `syntax` command, which allows to manually set the syntax to python.

Comment: I would be cool if there were a command for indent, similar to syntax

Comment: @Chiel92 Take a look at `:h 'indentexpr'` This allows you to set a indent function. However this is generally set when you source the indent file because the indent file defines the function at the same time